# How to get column Data Type from a row of Sqlite3 db - Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, column-types

```
for (int i=0; i< sqlite3_column_count(selectStatement); i++)                    
{

    int intValue = 0; 
    const char *strValue;
    switch (sqlite3_column_type(selectStatement,i)) 
    {
    }

}
```

How to get column Data Type from a row of Sqlite3 db

Android Equivalent Code where i have the cursor object globally and it is working fine:

```
public Object get(String name, QueryDbType type) throws Exception {

    Object retult = null;
    int index = cursor.getColumnIndex(name);
    switch (type) {
    case Text:
        retult = cursor.getString(index);
        break;
    case Int:
        retult = cursor.getInt(index);
        break;

    default:
        retult = cursor.getString(index);
        break;
    }
    return retult;
}
```

Comment: Not easy; Java is object-oriented and has a well integrated sqlite3 wrapper.  The base sqlite3 API is C and C isn't object-oriented.  You are therefore looking at a `union` or something like that, however how is it you don't know the column type already?

Comment: `sqlite3_column_type()` already does what you want. What is the problem?

Comment: He wants a C variant mechanism to capture the column value.

Comment: I have a table in which some field are TEXT and some rare BLOB but when i check sqlite3_column_type then am getting always 3. 3 means Text.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite is "typeless". This means that you can store any kind of data you want in any column of any table, regardless of the declared data type of that column. You can find more info [here.](http://www.sqlite.org/datatypes.html)

But, if you want to get the info about the declared data type of a column, you can do that by using the pragma table_info(table_name).

eg.

```
pragma table_info(Setting);
```

Then , you can iterate through the returned resultset and check for the data type you want to check.